# device tree and spi controller file

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, boot, spi, device-tree

why is the file spi_bcm2708.c is not present inside the path linux/drivers/spi and while inside the boot partition of pi the bcm2708-rpi-version.dts file is only present.how come kernal use the spi_bcm2708.c for this device tree.can anyone help me out in this?

because inside that dts file the compatible string is stated as compatible = "brcm,bcm2708". but the controller driver is spi_bcm2708.c.

and also when I enabled spi in raspi-config it showed that modprobe spi_bcm2708 not found.Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

spi_bcm2708 is deprecated.

The current SPI drivers are spi-bcm2835 (main SPI) and spi-bcm2835aux
 (auxiliary SPI).

Comment: can you tell me why is bcm2708-rpi-version.dts is used instead of bcm2835-rpi-version.dts

Comment: @thanujvashan I don't know.